# Show $xy\neq0$ is the same as $x\neq0 \wedge y \neq0$

Tags: field-theory, axioms

I have to show:
$$xy\neq0 \Leftrightarrow  x\neq0 \wedge y \neq0 $$

I think I can "simplify" it to this:
$$xy=0 \Leftrightarrow  x=0 \vee y=0 $$

Since $a\cdot0=0$ is an proven theorem, I can show:
$$x=0 \vee y=0 \rightarrow  xy=0 $$

But that is just one of the directions. How can I use the field axioms to show this theorem?

Comment: In any way of axiomatizing the concept of field I'm familiar with, $a\cdot0=0$ is **not** an axiom, it is a **theorem** that one proves using the axiom that multiplication distributes over addition. It might help, therefore, to actually list what you have been given as the axioms for a field.

Comment: Right, it only a theorem. The [list I have](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FieldAxioms.html) has 10 axioms.

Comment: (Off-topic: That's an interesting distinction Mathworld draws between additive and multiplicative distributivity ...)

Comment: Hint: Suppose that $xy=0$. If $x\ne 0$, then $x$ has a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: @queueoverflow: Note that you aren't "simplifying" the original question. Rather, you are replacing the statement you want to prove (which is of the form $\neg p\Longleftrightarrow \neg q$) with a statement which is logically equivalent to it (namely $p\Longleftrightarrow q$).

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Can I just multiply both sides with the inverse of $x$ and be done with it? $xyx^{-1}=0x^{-1}$ which collapses into $y=0$. Would that be axiomatic?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Okay, but it does not hurt, does it? Or is is not needed and I can somehow show the original statement directly?

Comment: Depends on your specific list of axioms, and previously proved theorems that you can quote, but probably yes. Out of habit, though it makes no real difference, I would multiply by $x^{-1}$ on the *left*.  Of course, this does one direction only, but it is the "harder" direction.

Comment: @queuoverflow: No, it doesn't necessarily hurt, nor is it a problem. I'm just saying that calling it a "simplification" is a misnomer. You aren't simplifying (you are not reducing the question to something 'smaller'), you are replacing the question with something which is logically equivalent to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to spell out what you're trying to show.

**Claim:** If $xy = 0$, then $x = 0$ or $y = 0$ (or both).

**Proof:** We'll consider two cases.

If $x = 0$ , then there is nothing to show (we already have one of $x$ and $y$ equal to 0, which is what we want).

If $x \neq 0$ , we hope to establish that $y = 0$ (since the conclusion we desire is that at least one of the two is equal to 0). Since $x \neq 0$ **and we are in a field**, the multiplicative inverse of $x$ exists.

With $x^{-1}$ in hand, how can you isolate $y$ in the equation $xy=0$ ? What do you learn about $y$ when you do so?

Comment: In case I can "multiply both sides", then I can simply do $x^{-1}xy = x^{-1}0$, obtaining $y=0$.

Comment: Exactly what you wanted, right?

Comment: Absolutely. I was just not sure, whether I am allowed do "divide by x" since it is not on the axiom list explicitly. But now I have both sides of my problem done. Thanks!

Comment: I think I see your confusion now. You are wondering whether "multiply both sides by something" is a legal maneuver when trying to prove something from axioms, correct? If so, think of the operation "multiply by $x^{-1}$" as a function $f$ (it is indeed a function). Since $xy = 0$, we know that $f(xy) = f(0)$, but this is just $x^{-1}xy = x^{-1}0$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Suppose that $xy=0$. If $x=0$, then certainly $x=0\vee y=0$. Otherwise, $x\neq0$. What do we know about non-zero elements of a field that would let us conclude that $y=0$?

Comment: I know that $0a=0$ for any $a$. Therefore, if I start with $y=0$ ($0=0$) and use this axiom to make it $xy=0$, then a non-zero $x$ would make the $y$ $0$. Is that a proof?

Comment: @queue, in the last "then" it looks like you're using the property you're supposed to be proving. Or do you have any particular reason in mind why $xy=0$ with a nonzero $x$ would imply $y=0$? You're supposed to _end_ with $y=0$, not start with it.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Valid point :-). How is this? $xy=0$, $(xy)\cdot 0=0$ , $x(y\cdot 0)=0$, [$y0=0$], $x0=0$, $x=0$. Vice versa for $y$.

Comment: @queue: That's a bunch of formulas. It's not clear to me how you think they relate to each other. What do the square brackets around $y0=0$ signify? Are you attempting to conclude $x=0$ from $x0=0$ (which won't work at all)? You need to be much more generous with the connecting prose in your reasoning.

Comment: I tried to start with $xy=0$ and then multiply everything by zero. The problem you pointed out is that $\cdot 0$ is a singular operation and that it does not have any inverse. So this train of thought wrecked as well.

Comment: @queue, multiplying everything by zero just loses every information the equation contains. Hint: you need to use the assumption that $x$ is nonzero, _and_ the knowledge that you're working in a field rather than a ring.

Comment: @queueoverflow If you assume $x\neq 0$, then you know $x^{-1}$ exists. Try multiplying $xy=0$ through by that. What can you conclude about $y$?

Answer (score 0):

This is much the same as the other answers, but you do not need to consider cases.  If you want to show that $p \implies q$, you can assume $p \wedge \neg q$ is true and derive a contradiction.

Suppose $x \neq 0$, $y \neq 0$, and assume $xy = 0$.  Then, $x$ and $y$ have inverses.  Hence, $xy$ does too (this needs formal justification).  But,...(this is where you come in).

Comment: I have $p \Longleftrightarrow q$ in this case. Isn't that a different story?

Comment: But $p \Longleftrightarrow q$ is the same as both $p \implies q$ and $q \implies p$.  You have already shown that $q \implies p$.

Comment: Okay, and the other is easy to show since one of $x$ and $y$ being 0, $0a=0$ immediately shows this.